# How to use chain.p7b with Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate

I wanted to setup a SSL website on Apache and applied for a certificate from my local ISP. All they sent me was a single file named chain.p7b.

I have always used certificates from other vendors without any issues but they usually provide two files to be configured as SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateChainFile in Apache.

Following instructions from several online resources, I opened the p7b file in Windows and extracted 4 certificates from the file. I then tried configuring Apache with one of the files and it worked, but shows a warning: The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided.

I though I have to use remaining 3 files as SSLCertificateChainFile and/or SSLCACertificateFile. I tried that but it didn't work so I am assuming it might be something completely different.

Anyone faced this issue before?

The following page http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21458997 talks about using a keystore but is that relevant to Apache?

Comment: Did your ISP not give you instructions?

Comment: Obviously not. They said "We provide standard SSL certificates.Customer should consult with exchange vendor or online documentation for certificate installation."

Comment: That certainly doesn't sound like a standard SSL certificate. At least not for an Apache web server. I would recommend you shop around before buying these things next time. :)

Comment: You are right. I have never bought anything from this particular ISP before, but this time I had no choice as the purchase was made by my client.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211591/export-p7b-file-with-all-the-certificate-chain-into-cer-file

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to find out:

1. [what kind of certificates does the Apache web server accept](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile)

   > SSLCertificateChainFile Directive
   >
   > This directive sets the optional all-in-one file where you can assemble the certificates of Certification Authorities (CA) which form the certificate chain of the server certificate. This starts with the issuing CA certificate of the server certificate and can range up to the root CA certificate. Such a file is simply the concatenation of the various **PEM-encoded CA Certificate files**, usually in certificate chain order.
2. [what is a `p7b` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions)

   > Certificate filename extensions
   >
   > .p7b, .p7c – PKCS#7 SignedData structure without data, just certificate(s) or CRL(s)
3. [what tools can convert from a `p7b` to a PEM encoded certificate](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs7.html)

Comment: I have seen the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211591/export-p7b-file-with-all-the-certificate-chain-into-cer-file and tried out several commands but nothing works. I was only able to extract that file when I tried from Windows.